# Using Nested IF statements to Hide a row

Tags: vba, excel

I have been attempting to hide a row on a spreadsheet based on two conditional target values in two target addresses. This works when I want it to check one target address, but not if I use two. I have not found the solution on this site. Here is the sample code:

```
If (Target.Address = "$G$2") And (Target.Value = "Yes") Then
    If (Target.Address = "$G$3") And (Target.Value = "Yes") Then
        Rows("4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
```

This works when I just use the first line:

```
If (Target.Address = "$G$2") And (Target.Value = "Yes") Then
    Rows("4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

But won't work when I put further conditions in. I'm not sure if this is a limitation with the .Hidden internal function, or if VBA doesn't like my nested IF statements.

I'd be grateful for any help,

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have solved my problem from the comments, I wasn't properly targeting two separate values, here is my fix.

```
If (Target.Address = "$G$2") And (Target.Value = "Yes") Then
    If (Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 7).Value = "Yes") Then

        Rows("4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
End If
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: what is `Target`? What are the conditions you want to be met to hide row 4?

Comment: If your `Target.Address` is equal to "$G$2" it will clearly pass the first `If` statement, but there's nothing changing the `Target.Address` before the very next statement checking if it's equal to "$G$3". I believe you're referring to two different `Target.Addresses` but your code isn't showing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the same object variable for being equal to two different values. By definition, they cannot be true at the same time. Assuming this is always done on the active sheet, you have to use the activesheet object and check the values of the cells in it.

```
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range

Set Rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("$G$2")
Set Rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("$G$3")

If Rng1.Value = "Yes" And Rng2.Value = "Yes" Then
        Rows("4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

Comment: This was my issue. Thank you.

Comment: If this solved your problem, then an upvote and an acceptance (check mark) would be a great way to show your thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Your two `If` statements are mutually exclusive, because if `Target.Address = "$G$2"`, it obviously can't *also* meet the condition `Target.Address = "$G$3"`.  I suspect you're looking for something more like this:

```
If Target.Value = "Yes" And (Target.Address = "$G$2" Or Target.Address = "$G$3") Then
    Rows("4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

Comment: I need both of these cells to be equal to "Yes", your line has an "Or" statement within it. I tried changing this to "And", but this hasn't fixed my problem. I see what you have said, but the logic behind the nested IFs seem sound to me.

Comment: @JackNicholls - You'll need to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40243564/edit) to include all of the relevant code then. I'm not exactly clear on how `Target` can be two different cells.

Comment: @JackNicholls that makes no sense unless `Target` is re-assigned between the two `If` conditions, but that's not in your question and nobody here can possibly guess that.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I have solved the issue, the re-assigning was my problem. Thanks. I am new to VBA and trying to get to grips with it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're after two different cells to be checked, say `Target1` and `Target2` be the variables referencing them:

```
If (Target1.Address = "$G$2") And (Target1.Value = "Yes") Then
    Rows("4").EntireRow.Hidden = (Target2.Address = "$G$3" And Target2.Value = "Yes") 
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do it this way:

```
If (Target.Address = "$G$2") And (LCase(Target.Value) = "yes") And (LCase(Target.Offset(1).Value) = "yes") Then
    Row("4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Although I would strongly suggest that you qualify `Row`

Comment: "Rows" is in the original question and built into Excel VBA. "Row" would have to be qualified, but that seems pointless seeing as there's already a built in object.